# Refresh page with new query string ....MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 3 project where you can edit a record, or clone it. When you click on the record to edit, the url looks like this:

```
    http://localhost/Products/Edit/?Id=123
```

If the user clicks clone, a popup window appears asking for a new name. The user enters a name then clicks proceed. An ajax call is made with the old id and new name:

```
         var formData = "Id="+@Model.Id+"&Name="+$('#txt').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Clone")',
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function(resp) {
                    //this is where i try to refresh the page with the newly created id
                    window.location.href = "@(Url.Action("Edit") + "/?Id=" + resp.NewId)";

            },
            error:function(data) {
            },
            complete:function() {
            }
        });
```

Here's my action:

```
 public ActionResult Copy(Inputmodel viewModel)
    {
        //this will populate the new id inside of my model object
        var model = Clone(viewModel);
        return View("Edit", model);
   }
```

Now i need to reload the browser with the newly created id, so the url should look like this:

```
    http://localhost/Products/Edit/?Id=456
```

I tried the above in my ajax call, but that didn't work. How do i achieve what i'm trying to do? Thanks

Comment: If you need to reload the page, why are you using an AJAX call?  Or maybe I just don't understand the scenario completely.

Comment: I'm using ajax because of the popup window where the user enters a new name

Comment: Oh, it's a separate window - sorry, thanks for clearing up my confusion =)  You might save yourself some trouble by using an in-browser modal dialog (rather than opening a new window).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not concatenating right.

Do it like this:

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Edit")"+"?Id=" + resp.NewId;
```

Or:

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Edit")?Id=" + resp.NewId;
```

Comment: Wow...a syntax error. All that matters is I got my answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for RedirectToAction.

Try replacing:

```
return View("Edit", model);
```

with

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit","Products",new {Id="456"}/*set query string*/);
```

Comment: My problem was a syntax error. I had my parenthesis wrong. But i will try you solution too.

Comment: @AnupamSingh he is calling action via ajax, ``RedirectToAction`` will not work

Comment: yes you are correct. will work only with simple post method(action)